# TypeError no implicit conversion of PicUploader into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, carrierwave, axlsx

I'm using `axlsx-rails` to generate excel sheets that contain the info that is in my User entity. the problem arises when i try to put an image in the excel sheet.  I'm using `carrierwave 0.11.2` and I've made sure that I have set it up correctly, I have the string column `profile_pic` that holds the image, I have the uploader `PicUploader` and it's mounted to User. the carrierwave implementation works fine, and the picture shows in the user's "show" page but when i try to follow the axlsx example to put the image in the sheet as such

```
 img = File.expand_path(@user.profile_pic, __FILE__)
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
        image.width=420
        image.height=669
    end
```

I get the TypeError `no implicit conversion of PicUploader into String`
Any idea what might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that `expand_path` expects a string, not a PicUploader class as parameter. Try

```
img = File.expand_path(@user.profile_pic.current_path, __FILE__)
```

Comment: kinda unrelated follow-up: the image seems to ignore my `image.start_at` and always starts at A1 (i can, however change the `end_at`). do you have any idea why this could be happening ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you're talking about :( open another question with the involved code, please.